# Как осуществляется сортировка массива и взаимодействие функций в Ruby?

Tags: массивы, ruby, функции

Есть функция создания квадратного массива:

```
def create_array array = []
  print "Пожалуйста введите размерность квадратного массива: "
  n = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts
  (0...n).each do |i|
    array[i] = []
    (0...n).each do |j|
      print "[#{i}, #{j}] = #{array[i] << rand(-30..30)}"
      puts
    end
  end
  puts "Массив: #{array.inspect}"
end
```

Есть функция сортировки массива:

```
def sort_dimensional_array_descending_optimized(array)
    swap = true
    rhythm = array.size - 1
    while swap
      swap = false
      for i in 0...rhythm
          swap |= array[i] > array[i + 1]  
          array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i] if array[i] > array [i + 1]
      end
      rhythm -= 1 
    end
    puts array.join(', ')
end
```

**Собственно проблема:** функция сортировки не сортирует массив, созданный из чисел или с помощью функции создания массива. Она сортирует только текстовые массивы. Пожалуйста, помогите исправить.(Мне больше нужно понять, поэтому буду очень рад развернутым комментариям!)

Comment: Нужен пример как пытаешься сортировать. Из приведённого примера это неясно. В методе который создаёт массив ты работаешь с двумерным массивом а при сортировке с одномерным. Плюс обязательно ли писать свою реализацию сортировки? Родные методы типа `sort` или `sort!` не подходят?

Comment: Так, а вы какой массив хотите отсортировать? Числовой или строковый или смешаный?

Comment: Числовой, строковый функция сортирует нормально.

Comment: @anoam я пытаюсь разобраться в том, как в  Ruby сортируются многомерные массивы, поэтому написал свою функцию(видно не правильно написал). Приведенная выше функция сортировки должна сортировать двумерный массив по возрастанию(пузырьком).

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста принцип сортировки многомерных массивов в Ruby. (До этого имел дело с С)

Answer (score 1):

```
class MatrixSorter

    attr_reader :matrix

    def initialize(matrix)
        @matrix = matrix
    end

    def sort!
        @matrix =
          matrix.flatten.sort.each_slice(matrix.size).to_a
    end

end

array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 0], [7, 7, 6]]

matrix_sorter = MatrixSorter.new(array)
matrix_sorter.sort!
p matrix_sorter.matrix.inspect
```

Я совершенно не помню как правильно должен сортироваться двумерный массив. По-этому сделал как сообразил: сортируем все строки, а потом строки между собой сравниваем по первому элементу.

Поскольку ruby, всё-таки, объектно-ориентированный язык, сортировку выполнил в виде класса. Ввод так же пропустил, т.к. про него вопросов не было.
Сортировать ручной перестановкой элементов в руби не стоит. Всё это язык умеет сам, и родные сортировки оптимизированы.

Честно говоря, очень слабо представляю что здесь нужно дополнительно объяснить. Так что спрашивай в комментах - дополню ответ.
И если нужна именно ручная сортировка по каким-то причинам так же пиши в комментах - дополню решение.

UPD.:

1. Я не совсем уверен что двумерный массив сортируется именно так, но изменил пример чтобы он сортировался таким образом.
   Принцип такой `flatten` - преобразует массив в одномерный, `sort` - сортирует его, `each_slice(matrix.size)` разбивает на группы, каждая по `matrix.size` (считаем что массив "квадратный"). А поскольку `each_slice` возвращает объект класса `Enumerator` то преобразуем его обратно в массив.
2. К сожалению, код читается трудно. Но мне кажется проблема вот в этом:

   > array3[i][j], array3[i + 1][j + 1] = array3[j + 1][i + 1]

С левой стороны две переменных, с правой только одна.

3. matrix.sort!{ |arr1, arr2| arr1.first <=> arr2.first } - метод `sort` [может принимать в качестве аргуметра](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) блок, который выполняется в процессе сортировки.

Поскольку двумерный массив это, фактически, массив массивов то мы сначала сортировали каждый массив. `(&:sort!)` - сокращённая (и предпочтительная) форма. Полностью это выглядело бы как matrix.each { |array| array.sort! }

4.

> И в первом отрывке вашего кода тоже, не понятно функция сама себя вызывает или вызывается метод sort! для класса Array?

Вот это не понял совсем. Сначала создаём объект класса `MatrixSorter` а потом вызываем метод, определённый в этом классе `sort!`. Который, внутри, вызывает стандартные методы массива.

Comment: не могу понять как происходит сортировка. То есть, если взять массив: array3 = [[14, 12, 3, 4],[13, 1, 15, 6],[9, 7, 11, 2],[5, 16, 10, 8]], то после сортировки получим такой массив: [[1, 6, 13, 15], [2, 7, 9, 11], [3, 4, 12, 14], [5, 8, 10, 16]]. Он вроде отсортирован, но не до конца. в общем, как сделать так, чтобы числа в нем шли по порядку ( то есть  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])

Comment: Вот допустим сортировка:                                                                 'while swap
  swap = false
  for i in 0..size
    for j in 0..size
    swap = true if array3[i][j] > array3[i + 1][j + 1]
    array3[i][j], array3[i + 1][j + 1] = array3[j + 1][i + 1]
    end
  end
end' Должна работать, но не работает(( Выдает кучу ошибок и я не пойму что не так(

Comment: так же не могу понять в вашем коде вот это:(&:sort!) - & и ":" - для чего нужны? а так же: matrix.sort!{ |arr1, arr2| arr1.first <=> arr2.first } - получается функция сама себя вызывает, но как происходит обмен? И в первом отрывке вашего кода тоже, не понятно функция сама себя вызывает или вызывается метод sort! для класса Array?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для сортировки встроенную функцию [`#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) модуля `Enumerable`:

```
array.sort { |x, y| x <=> y }
```

Comment: Каким образом используя эту конструкцию я могу отсортировать двумерный массив? Она ничего не делает. Пример: исходный массив a = [[-2, -16, -6], [-12, -30, 3], [6, -24, -11]]; p a.sort { |x, y| x <=> y } #выводит: [[-12, -30, 3], [-2, -16, -6], [6, -24, -11]]

Comment: @ToshiDono это как пример, зависит от задачи что вы хотите получить на выходе ))) обновите пост выходным и выходным массивом